# Get the id attribute of this with d3

Tags: d3.js

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonpyc/kxqLLmyz/)

```
lineID = d3.select(this.firstChild).attr('id'); // setting the line id
textID = d3.select(this.lastChild).attr('id'); // setting the text id
```

In this case, I want the line to move with label when its dragged.
So only the x2 and y2 attributes of the line will be updated and x1 and y1 of the lines should stay the same.
The firstChild and lastChild usage here is probably not the ideal solution. 
The x1 and y1 is hardcoded now, and I don't know how to return the values dynamically.

Comment: Why don't you simply translate the `g` elements?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff he wants `x1`, `y1` to remain the same. That wouldn't work if you translate `g`s (and he doesn't have them anyway, pity...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your drag on the `.text` selection, as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1557377), not on the `svg` root element.

```
g.selectAll(".text")
    ...
    .call(drag);
```

Then, to access the ids:

```
var textID = this.id; // this = current text element
var lineID = 'line' + textID.slice(-1); // your custom line id
```

**Edit**

Also, if you want to leave `x1` and `y1` the same, you can just omit them in your update behavior:

```
d3.select("#"+ lineID)
    .attr("x2", newx2)
    .attr("y2", newy2);
```

And so that the `.text` doesn't jump on drag, just use `transform` everywhere without setting `x` and `y` offsets (they will be 0 by default).

```
g.selectAll(".text")
    ... // no .attr('x', ...) or y here
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + (d.x + 10) + "," + (d.y - 30) + ")";
    })
    ...;
```

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pnc63mvg/).

Comment: somehow the translate bit didn't work well on the actual project, probably didn't set it up properly. Anyway, thanks.